# What type of connector is this?

Tags: connector

It's connecting to the rear brake light diffuser, Renault Clio 5.

I need two male/female connectors to extend the cable length.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You aren't likely to find ready made extensions for that, you may be able to buy the connectors and make them, if you can find the type. I suspect you'll need to chop the wires and crimp/solder in extensions instead.

Comment: It can be difficult to impossible to find an exact match to this.  You can probably find the connector "family" but often, especially in automotive use, these are custom "keyed" to make incorrect connections impossible.  You might be able to take a generic version and modify it but no guarantees.  Start by identifying the manufacturer.  Common ones are AMP, Amphenol, TE, Molex, but there are many others.

Comment: Agree with @GdD here ... your best bet is to just lengthen the wires which are already there.

Comment: If you really need to make a non-permanent extension, you could just replace the connectors with something readily available.